# Как удалить клавиатуру?(Python telegram bot, keyboard_remove)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, клавиатура

Python3+, requests

Отправляю кнопку с запросом номера:

```
reply_markup = {'keyboard': [[{'text':'contact', 'request_contact':True}]]}
кнопка появляется и работает, но как ее потом убрать?
```

вариант:

```
reply_markup = {'keyboard': [[{'text':'contact', 'request_contact':True, 'one_time_keyboard':True}]]}
```

не помог.
Такой вариант:

```
reply_markup = {'keyboard':[[{'Keyboard_Remove':True}]]}
```

тоже ничего не меняет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. удалить кнопки так и не вышло, нашел другой подход:

отправляем запрос контакта.

> > > reply_markup = {'keyboard': [[{'text':'contactrequest', 'request_contact':True}]], 'one_time_keyboard':True, 'resize_keyboard': True}
> > > data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text':'test', 'reply_markup': json.dumps(reply_markup)}
> > > r = requests.post(URL, data)

После полученного номера, отправляем другую клавиатуру

> > > reply_markup = {'keyboard': [['Yes', 'No']], "resize_keyboard": True, 'one_time_keyboard':True}
> > > data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': 'test', 'reply_markup': json.dumps(reply_markup)}
> > > r = requests.post(URL, data)

а вот такую клавиатуру уже можно и удалить

> > > reply_markup = {'remove_keyboard':True}
> > > data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': 'test', 'reply_markup': json.dumps(reply_markup)}
> > > r = requests.post(URL, data)

Answer (score 1):

Когда получаете следующее сообщение, добавьте строку:

`await message.answer("Клавиатура скрыта", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())`